# Button Click Test Failing with Jest / VueJS

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to initiate a button click on a image, but when running the test, it keeps erroring out with `find did not return cal-modal, cannot call trigger() on empty Wrapper`

What am I doing wrong? Very very simplified code below:

***CALENDAR.VUE***

```
<template>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                    <b-img ref='cal-modal' id='cal-modal' class="cal-icon" @click="displayCal" v-b-modal.date-time-modal src="/static/img/ico.png"></b-img>
                </div>

</template>
```

***TEST FILE***

```
import {createLocalVue, mount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import Calendar from '@/components/Calendar.vue'
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(BootstrapVue)


  it('display cal', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(Calendar, {localVue});
      wrapper
          .find('cal-modal')
          .trigger('click')
  })
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a `ref` selector or an `id` selector. Like this ..

`wrapper.find({ ref: 'cal-modal' })`

Or

`wrapper.find('#cal-modal')`